# Get text of htlm inline element class with python selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get a text of a webpage which is within an inline Element. 
The element looks like:

```
   <span id="some_text" class="labelRight">SOME_TEXT</span>
```

I want to get the SOME_TEXT part.

I already tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('').get_text
driver.find_element_by_id('').get_attribute("class")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_contentBody_lblCount').text
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved my problem!